# Python: Retrieve list of sockets on current machine?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm brand new to Python (as of last week) and I'm still getting to grips with the basics so please excuse any ignorance I display.

As part of my homework I have been asked to make a basic port scanner and one of the functions I have to include is the retrieval of a list of sockets on the current machine. I have been looking around and managed to piece together a piece of code that allows me to enter the IP of the machine I wish to scan but I want to try and make it so it automatically scans whichever machine it is running on.

```
    elif (userChoice == "4"):

    print("You selected " + userChoice)

    try:

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # s will be equal to the command looking for the IPV4 addresses

    except socket.error:

        sys.exit("Failed to create socket.")  # error handling message to be printed to the console should a socket failed to be created

    print("Socket created")

    hostAddress = input("Please enter host address to scan - example 'www.server.com': ")
    print ("You entered " + hostAddress )

    try:
        remoteIP = socket.gethostbyname(hostAddress)

    except socket.gaierror:

            sys.exit("Hostname could not be resolved exiting")

            ret = input("Hit return to go back to the menu")

            continue

    print("IP address of " + hostAddress + ' is ' + remoteIP)
```

This is my code so far. If anyone could help me out or tell me if I'm even going in the right direction with this I would be very grateful.

Also, with me being a noob, if anyone has any suggestions for good reading materials to help me get to get to grips with the basics I would very much appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: `hostAddress = 'localhost'` or alternatively `hostAddress = '127.0.0.1'`?

Answer (score 0):

To check open ports on remote server-

```
# For input hostAddress
remoteIP = socket.gethostbyname(hostAddress)
for port in range(1,1025):  
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        result = sock.connect_ex((remoteIP, port))
        if result == 0:
            print("Port %s:  Open"%port)
        sock.close()

=> Port 80:   Open
```